# Handling exception thrown by service in spring integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

```
@Service
public class TradeService {

    @Autowired
    private JmsMessageSender jmsMessageSender;

    @Async
    public Future<TradeProcessingContext> submitTradeForProcessing(final Trade trade) {
        TradeProcessingContext tradeProcessingContext = new TradeProcessingContext();

        try {
            send(trade);
            updateStatus(tradeProcessingContext);
            tradeProcessingContext.setEventState(TradeStatus.SUCCESS);
            return new AsyncResult<>(tradeProcessingContext);
        } catch (TradeProcessingException ex) {
            tradeProcessingContext.setEventState(TradeStatus.FAILED);
            return new AsyncResult<>(tradeProcessingContext);
        }
    }


    private void send(final Trade trade) throws TradeProcessingException {
        Optional<String> xmlTradeMessage = XmlParserUtil.marshall(trade);

        if (xmlTradeMessage.isPresent()) {
            try {
                jmsMessageSender.sendMessage(aqname, xmlTradeMessage.get());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Sending message failed, due to : " + e, e);
                throw new TradeProcessingException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have the above `Service` class which is called by my `Service Activators`.

I am trying to understand how I should be handling errors in my spring integration application.

For example, I want to deal with different types of exception and determine the best course of action i.e. `send()` will be jms related exceptions, `updateStatus()` will be database related exceptions.

Either of these operations could fail in which case I want to pick them up from an error channel but I am unsure how to structure and plug this in. I have a handler:

```
@MessageEndpoint
public class Handler {
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = TRADE_CHANNEL)
    public void handle(final Trade trade) {
        submitTradeForProcessing(trade)
    }
}
```

and Gateaway as follows:

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface TradeGateaway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "tradeChannel")
    void processEvent(Trade trade);

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "processUnprocessed")
    void unprocessedEvent(String eventID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For different types of exceptions you can consider to use [`ErrorMessageExceptionTypeRouter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#router-implementations-exception-router):

```
/**
 * A Message Router that resolves the target {@link MessageChannel} for
 * messages whose payload is a {@link Throwable}.
 * The channel resolution is based upon the most specific cause
 * of the error for which a channel-mapping exists.
 * <p>
 * The channel-mapping can be specified for the super classes to avoid mapping duplication
 * for the particular exception implementation.
 *
 * @author Mark Fisher
 * @author Oleg Zhurakousky
 * @author Artem Bilan
 */
public class ErrorMessageExceptionTypeRouter extends AbstractMappingMessageRouter {
```

So, you subscribe this to the mentioned error channel and do the logic for each particular exception separately.